# Помогите пожалуйста в html & css

Tags: html, css

возникла проблема как двигать пнг картинку, не могу переместить его на верх по середите Помогите пожалуйста.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.image_o {}
```

```html
<div class="image_o">
  <img src="hello.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Предоставьте минимальный код для воспроизведения проблемы..

Comment: Не настолько минимальный.

Answer (score 1):

Родителю говорим центрировать изображение, а img делаем inline-block.

На inline-block элементы срабатывают text-align параметры.

```css
.image_o {
  text-align: center
}

.image_o img {
  display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<div class="image_o">
  <img src="hello.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: и опять ни строчки пояснений...